# Plotly Dash Key Error 0 while filtering data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to update my line plot when I hover over a certain id in `Plotly Dash`. I have tried multiple ways of filtering out the data frame containing the `'id'`, where I can then further filter down to just the 'heart rate' columns. It raised an error of `KeyError 0` or `uncomparable length` when run on `Plotly Dash`. Will appreciate if anyone can help in debugging! Thanks!

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('heart-rate-time-series', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('crossfilter-indicator-scatter', 'hoverData')])
def update_heart_rate_timeseries(hoverData):
    id = hoverData['points'][0]['customdata']
    id_str = str(id)
    # dff = pd.DataFrame()
    # dff = df[df['icustay_id'].isin([id])] -- keyerror :0
    # dff = df.loc[:, df['icustay_id'].str.contains(id_str)]
    ## dff = df.loc[lambda df: df['icustay_id'] == id] # ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (10184,), (1,))
    dff = df.loc[df['icustay_id'].apply(lambda x: x == id)]
    dff = dff.loc[:, dff.columns.to_series().str.contains("heart_rate")]
    dff_transpose = dff.transpose()
    dff_transpose['time'] = range(0, len(dff_transpose))
    fig = px.line(dff, x = dff_transpose['time'], y = dff_transpose[0])
    fig.update_traces(mode='lines+markers')
    fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False)
    title = 'Patient id: <b>{}</b><br>{}'.format(id, 'Heart rate against time(in hours)')
    fig.add_annotation(x=0, y=0.89, xanchor='left', yanchor='bottom',
                       xref='paper', yref='paper', showarrow=False, align='left',
                       text=title)
    fig.update_layout(height=230, margin={'l': 20, 'b': 30, 'r': 10, 't': 10})
    return fig
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: full error should show you which line makes problem so you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables in this line. It can help to see what makes problem.